# replace space with comma for words that only have space between them regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I trying to replace spaces with comma for words that only have space between them
like this example

> Color  :  NavyBlue      TrainLength : FloorLength  USSize : 6   shipping
> : standard

it should be like this

> Color : NavyBlue,TrainLength : FloorLength,USSize : 6,shipping :
> standard

where it has  commas between these variants

I can only match spaces between words that have colons

```
\s*:\s*
```

but I need a way to match spaces between words that has no colon

for example  consider the dots as space

> don't match this ...:...
>
> but match this NavyBlue.....TrainLength

match the spaces only not the words

to test it [test real example](http://regexr.com/4sh9d)

Comment: `.replace(/([a-z0-9]) ([a-z0-9])/gi, "$1,$2");`

Comment: @ASDFGerte didn't work   try from the link I updated  in the question

Comment: Well, if you change the format, of course a regex written for the original one is highly likely to not work...

Comment: @ASDFGerte What I need is to match the space between the variants  to replace it with comma  like the example I updated but in your example it will match  (words space words )  which  I don't want to match any words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
let s1 = " Color  :  NavyBlue      TrainLength : FloorLength  USSize : 6   shipping";
let r1 = s1.replace(/(\w+)\s+(\w+)/g, "$1,$2");
console.log(r1);

let s2 = "Color : NavyBlue TrainLength : FloorLength USSize : 6 shipping : standard";
let r2 = s2.replace(/(\w+)\s+(\w+)/g, "$1,$2");
console.log(r2);
```